# Save the values after realloc inside the realloc

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, realloc

I hope that on this question, I would give a better bakcground for my problem.

I have a `struct sth`:

```
typedef struct sth {
    int* tab;
    int  length;
}
```

and I have a array of structs `sth`. However, in this function I pass only `sths`. In the presented code, I change the values in tab array - add values in parallel cells. If I don't use `realloc`, the function works fine.

However, if I use `realloc`, the values are set to zero after return from the function. Inside the function, as I have checked, the values are changed after realloc.

```
#define ELEM_IN_CELL 4
    
void (sth a, sth b) {
    //changes i-th values a.tab[i] with b.tab[i] - works correctly
     
    int help = 67;
    if (I need to resize a.tab to bigger) { 
        if (i == a.length) {  //If I add a new cell
            if (i*ELEM_IN_CELL*sizeof(int) >= a.length*ELEM_IN_CELL*sizeof(int)) {
                a.tab = realloc(a.tab, 2*a.length*ELEM_IN_CELL*sizeof(int)+2;  //The probable problem
                                }
                    a.tab[i++] = help;
                  a.length++;
                printf(a.tab[i-1]); //Displays 67
            }
        }
    }
```

I know, that `realloc` returns a pointer to the amount of memory and saves the previous content. On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) I have read, that it can also copy the content and free the old block and I have started to wonder if it is a clue for an explanation, because `printf` inside the function works - therefore there is sufficient amount of memory (If there is not enough memory, the old memory block is not freed and null pointer is returned.). Is this a case to use a pointer-to-pointer? How?

Do you see any explanation or solution to the problem?

Comment: `realloc(a,...` `a` is a *Copy Of* the struct from the caller. Pass the *Address Of* the struct, e.g. `void (sth *a, sth *b)`

Comment: It is difficult to be certain because what you have presented is not valid C code, but you appear to be stumbling over the fact that arguments to C functions are passed *by value*.

Comment: You don't seem to have updated `a.length` after the reallocation.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It is quite sad, that the question had become closed even before I have read your comments, but I will certainly check your suggestions.

Comment: if you believe your question is not a duplicate then edit and explain and it'll be reopen soon

Comment: After a battle I have found out, that the problem was with the function to print out the result outside the function